# Appstore always throws error Missing App Icon

Tags: app-store, phonegap-build

I'm developing an mobile app with jquery mobile. Then I upload it at build.phonegap.com. With the .ipa file I get from phonegap-build I once managed to upload the app with the Application Loader. Now we had to do some bugfixes and I'm not able to upload the app anymore. 
I'm getting always the same error: 
ITMS-90704: Missing App Icon - An app icon measuring 1024 by 1024 pixels in PNG format must be included in the Asset Catalog of apps built for iOS, iPadOS, or watchOS. Without this icon, apps cannot be submitted for review. For details, see https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/app-icon/.

In Appstore Connect I've also uploaded the App Icon.

Here is my config.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget
  id="at.digitallaut.dlcards"
  version="1.0.13"
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
  <name>DI Card</name>
  <description>Create your Business Cards</description>
  <author email="pucher@digitallaut.at" href="https://www.digitallaut.at">
    Digital Laut GmbH
  </author>
  <content src="index.html" />

  <!-- preferences -->
  <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-7.0.1" />
  <!-- preference name='pgb-builder-version' value='1' / -->
  <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="21" />
  <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="28" />
  <preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="standard" />
  <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="false" />
  <preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
  <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#333333" />
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" />
  <!-- plugins -->
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" source="npm" spec="~2">
    <variable name="CAMERA_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="You can use camera pictures as background images for your business cards." />
    <variable name="PHOTOLIBRARY_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="You can select pictures from your gallery as background images for your business cards." />
  </plugin>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-contacts" source="npm" spec="~2.0.1">
    <variable name="CONTACTS_USAGE_DESCRIPTION" value="You can select one of your saved contacts and create a business card from this data." />
  </plugin>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" source="npm" spec="~1.3.0" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" source="npm" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-statusbar" source="npm" spec="~2.1.2" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" spec="~1.2.1" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" source="npm" version="3.0.0"/>
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" source="npm" version="1.3.0"/>

  <!-- icons and screens android -->
  <platform name="android">
    <splash platform="android" qualifier="port-ldpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-ldpi.png" />
    <splash platform="android" qualifier="port-mdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-mdpi.png" />
    <splash platform="android" qualifier="port-hdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-hdpi.png" />
    <splash platform="android" qualifier="port-xhdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-xhdpi.png" />
    <splash platform="android" qualifier="land-ldpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-ldpi.png" />
    <splash platform="android" qualifier="land-mdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-mdpi.png" />
    <splash platform="android" qualifier="land-hdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-hdpi.png" />
    <splash platform="android" qualifier="land-xhdpi" src="res/screen/android/splash-port-xhdpi.png" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/ldpi.png" density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/xxhdpi.png" density="xxhdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icon/android/xxxhdpi.png" density="xxxhdpi" />
  </platform>

  <!-- icons and screens ios -->
  <platform name="ios">
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/default_iphone.png" width="320" height="480"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="960"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait~ipad.png" width="768" height="1024"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Portrait@2x~ipad.png" width="1536" height="2048"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape~ipad.png" width="1024" height="768"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape@2x~ipad.png" width="2048" height="1536"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-568h@2x~iphone.png" width="640" height="1136"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-667h.png" width="750" height="1334"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-736h.png" width="1242" height="2208"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default-Landscape-736h.png" width="2208" height="1242"/>
    <!-- iOS 8.0+ -->
     <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon.png" width="1024" height="1024" />
    <!-- iPhone 6 Plus  -->
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-60@3x.png" width="180" height="180" />
    <!-- iOS 7.0+ -->
    <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  -->
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-60@2x.png" width="120" height="120" />
    <!-- iPad -->
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-76@2x.png" width="152" height="152" />
    <!-- iOS 6.1 -->
    <!-- Spotlight Icon -->
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-small-40.png" width="40" height="40" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-small-40@2x.png" width="80" height="80" />
    <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch -->
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon.png" width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon@2x.png" width="114" height="114" />
    <!-- iPad -->
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-72@2x.png" width="144" height="144" />
    <!-- iPhone Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-small@2x.png" width="58" height="58" />
    <!-- iPad Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-small-50.png" width="50" height="50" />
    <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-small-50@2x.png" width="100" height="100" />
  </platform>

  <!-- default icon and screen -->
  <splash src="splash.png" />
  <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon.png" width="1024" height="1024" />

  <!-- ios permissions -->
  <edit-config platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist" parent="NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription" mode="overwrite">
    <string>You can select pictures from your gallery as background images for your business cards.</string>
  </edit-config>
  <edit-config platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist" parent="NSCameraUsageDescription" mode="overwrite">
    <string>You can use camera pictures as background images for your business cards. </string>
</edit-config>
  <edit-config platform="ios" target="*-Info.plist" parent="NSContactsUsageDescription" mode="overwrite">>
    <string>You can select one of your saved contacts and create a business card from this data.</string>
  </edit-config>

  <!-- android permissions -->
  <gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest" mode="delete">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
  </gap:config-file>
  <gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest" mode="add">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  </gap:config-file>

  <!-- access rules -->
  <access origin="*" />
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
  <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
  <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
  <platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />  
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
  </platform>
</widget>
```

I've already tried all variations with and without the phonegap-version preference tag, it makes no difference. 
As I build the app with the online tool build.phonegap.com “Your project -> Images.xcassets->AppIcon" is not a possibility for me.

Any help appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution for phonegap build...

Add this to config.xml...

```
 <preference name="phonegap-version" value="cli-7.1.0" />
```

Now go through all your icons and make sure your saved PNGs don't include transparency. You can also use JPGs too. For me the main logo was saved with transparency (by default). Hence the error.

ALSO - please note, if using Phonegap Build and CLI-9.0.0 they have messed up the directory structure a little with regards to images and google-services.json and googleservice-info.plist. Place your images in a www/res/ folder (you can choose another name if you like) BUT when referencing the file src DO NOT INCLUDE WWW, so if your image is "www/res/android/icons.png" your src in the config.xml would be "res/android/icons.png". Similar thing with google-services.json and googleservice-info.plist, you MUST place them inside the www folder but when referencing them in config.xml, DO NOT INCLUDE WWW.

BUT - if you are compiling locally (not via Phonegap Build), you MUST reference the WWW, and you DON'T need to include the google service files inside the www (you can place them in the same folder as config.xml).

It's a real mess.

Comment: thanks i will give it a try and report here afterwards. my app store icon (1024x1024) is without transparency, the other icons are with transparency (but it worked to upload it this way a few weeks ago). I will give them a white background.

Comment: Also, if you get any errors about missing icons there is a list of required sizes here: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/images.html

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. Again the missing app icon error. I've changed the phonegap-version in config.xml and all the images to png with white background. Following your link it seems that i have all the required icons. But I get the same error again. Also tried to ask apple but I have to wait about 2 days for an answer. Thank you anyway, it was worth trying it.

Comment: The only other thing I did was to move the icons from the default icon location. Try moving all the images to an "icons" folder in www. Then target it from the config.xml like this:
   <icon height="1024" width="1024" src="icons/icon1024x1024.png" />

Comment: Finally it worked :-) I changed all transparent icons to have a background and had to add two more icons (following the docs for phonegap cli version 7.1.0) 
<icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-83.5@2x.png" width="167" height="167" /> and <icon src="res/icon/ios/icon-167.png" width="167" height="167" />
Thank you so much for your support!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, no real solution for Phonegap here. But I did ran into a similar issue with Cordova. I managed to fix it by adding the app icon manually in in my Xcode workspace (Resources > Images.xcassets > AppIcon) before archiving the app. Hope this helps someone!